# How can we protect our image being copied from our web site

Tags: asp.net, html

How can we protect our image being copied from our web site?

Can we disable copying image content from our website or any?

Comment: If it is displayed on the user system, then he can always take a screen shot

Comment: Maybe a good question to ask here http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24586/laws-legal-questions?referrer=z6SL0cFFhmqHRFwcsNCJtQ2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot stop an image from being downloaded from your web site. If this image is visible somehow on the site it means that clients already have it. You could add watermarks to the original to claim copyright. Some other techniques might involve incorporating the image into a Flash movie which would make it harder but not impossible to retrieve.

IMHO clearly stating copyright ownership of the images somewhere on your site should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot protect your images from copying. You can add watermark or some other artefact to it to discourage people from copying it, but you cannot prevent it (if you want it to be shown on your webpage, it is publicly available).

You may find this article as useful: [Your images are a virus. They are EVERYWHERE on the Internet](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YourImagesAreAVirusTheyAreEVERYWHEREOnTheInternet.aspx)

Comment: :) he is a great showman and has blog post for almost anything :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent image copying from your website, if it is served to the clients' browsers it can be copied.

Answer (score 1):

"User saw your images" means, he/she have already downloaded to his computer. But maybe you could put some trick to block users who are not advance on computer usage.

For example;

- [Disabling right click](http://www.reconn.us/content/view/36/45/) with javascript etc. (Not block us but blocks someones :) ) as [described](http://www.reconn.us/content/view/36/45/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a script and a transparent Gif or PNG overlay that is positioned over the image.
If the user back click they would end up with a blank image instead. This can be a little frustrating for them, and can sometimes be a bit difficult to figure out.

This may offer some low level help, unless the person is using a screen capture tool.